# JavaFX 8 TableView, How do I completely bypass the default column sorting behavior, and enable my own

Tags: tableview, javafx-8, columnsorting

The short version; I have a database that I have presorted 30 ArrayLists corresponding to 15 columns. 15 are presorted ascending, 15 are presorted descending; lColumn1, lColumn2, lColumn3 ... rColumn1, rColumn2, rColumn3 (the preceding "l" lets me know it's a list, the preceding "r" tells me its a reverse list. So "rColumn3" tells me this ListArray has Column 3 sorted in descending order.

When I click on the column header, I don't need or want any of the default sorting methods, including the up/down arrows. All I need is to @Override the default behavior so that when I click on a column header

1. The table column header click accesses my method which determines which
2. ListArray to load into the table and then
3. loads that array as an ObservableList.

I have working code for parts 2 and 3 above. How do I do 1? - override the default sorting behavior so the table column click bypasses all the default sorting behavior and accesses only my method?

More detail for those who don't like short versions:

I have a remote database I'm accessing that has approximately 100 lines that are downloaded into an array which become table rows, with each line (row) subsequently broken up into 15 columns. Before editing, each line is a string containing both numbers and strings, which, when broken down into cells, many cells contain both; 25°, or 87%, etc. To sort most of the table properly, I have to first remove the letter characters and then compare the resulting numbers so I can sort them as a number instead of as a string. To accomplish this, I have created 30 ArrayLists that are presorted and ready to be loaded directly into the table when needed.

Attempting to bypass TableView's default sorting methods, I have the following:

```
table  = new TableView<Person>() {
 @Override
 public void sort() {
  setColumns();
 }
};
```

And for each column:

```
firstCol.sortTypeProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<TableColumn.SortType>() {
 @Override
 public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends TableColumn.SortType> observable, TableColumn.SortType oldValue, TableColumn.SortType newValue)
 {
  firstCol.setSortNode(null); // This line does nothing
  String result = "";
  if ( sc.getVal() == 0 ) { result = (sc.getDirection().equals("ASCENDING") ? "DESCENDING" : "ASCENDING"); }
  else { result = "ASCENDING"; }
  sc.setDirection(result);
  sc.setVal(0);
 }
});
```

This does load the correct presorted ListArray as desired (usually after a half dozen clicks or so), but the up/down arrows still appear (don't need nor want them), it still follows the default 3 toggle options - up, down, and the no arrow "I'm ignoring your click" option.

How do I set this up so when I click on the TableColumn header, the click is recognized, but I'm able to @Override all default sorting behavior and access my own methods instead?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [James D](http://iswwwup.com/profile/1390316/james-d) for nudging me in the right direction.

I needed to change the column header from text to a graphic, which allowed me to set a mouse click listener. The following code is working (relevant code only):

```
TableColumn<Person, String> firstCol  = new TableColumn<>( ); // Do not include a TableColumn name here or it will be duplicated on the table
Label firstHeader = new Label( "Name" ); // Put the TableColumn name here: = new Label( "Name") 
firstCol.setGraphic(firstHeader); 
firstCol.setSortable(false);
firstCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
tractorHeader.addEventHandler(MouseEvent.MOUSE_CLICKED, new EventHandler<MouseEvent>()
{
 @Override
 public void handle(final MouseEvent e) 
 {
  System.out.println("Mouse Event Detected: " + e.toString());
  String result = "";
  if ( sc.getVal() == 0 ) { result = (sc.getDirection().equals("ASCENDING") ? "DESCENDING" : "ASCENDING"); }
  else { result = "ASCENDING"; }
  sc.setDirection(result);    // Store last sort direction request
  sc.setVal(0);               // Store last column number sorted
  setColumns();               // Method to set table ObservableList to the correct presorted ObservableList
 }
});
```